# Difference between Double and triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

Hi all I am going to be starting multivariable calc and I am trying to read up but I can't seem to quite grasp this exactly yet. What are the differences between double and triple integrals? I am under the impression that they both are used for 3 dimensional volumes. Is there any time one is preferred/more precise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double integral is used for integrating over a two-dimensional region, while a triple integral is used for integrating over a three-dimensional region. For instance, even though we visualize a sphere as sitting inside of 3-dimensional space, the sphere itself is two dimensional (remember that "sphere" only refers to the surface, while "ball" refers to the volume enclosed by the sphere). Hence, we would integrate over sphere with a double integral, but we would use a triple integral to integrate over the volume that the sphere bounds.